# How to play a video forever in UWP and make a certain portion clickable

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i'm trying to play the video forever and want a certain position to be clickable in that video .Any help would be appreciated.
Xaml

```
<Grid>

        <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement"
                          Source="/Video/main.mp4"

             CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"/>
    </Grid>
```

Refer screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overlay an element on top of the video - if you know the height and width of that, which you should you can have a control such as a Canvas control and attach a click event to this, but have no image with the height and width of it being the region where the sign is, and it's top and left margins so it will overlap that part of the video, then you can respond to the event to navigate to the other page as needed, remember to make the background colour of the Canvas transparent rather than nothing so the events are picked up

Answer (score 0):

Since only a small part of the page is animated and clickable you can use Animated GIF to achieve this ..

Here is a Link to the Github Sample for Animated Gif in XAML [Link Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlAnimatedGif)

Also, to use this you will need to add XAML Animated GIF nuget package in you project [Link here.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamlAnimatedGif/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: the image which is provided is part of mp4 video file and i need to make it clickable and also want to play this video forever unless until any body click on that 'More Apps' icon and it redirect to other screen